# Local Azure Search for development

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

Is there a way to test the Azure Search in local development environment? Without actually connecting to Azure. That would work offline.
I'm thinking of a something like the Azure Storage emulator.

Comment: There isn't. Interested in your scenario for this - offline development? Isolating for unit tests? Something else? Thanks!

Comment: Speed & Cost are the main factors. Each developer has their own database etc, so they need their own search as well. But testing as mentioned is important, too. Generally: Not being dependent on an internet connection is a plus.

Comment: For isolation as far as unit tests are concerned, it's better to define a higher level search interface that makes sense for your app, and mock that.

For giving each dev their own index, please vote for this [UserVoice suggestion](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/6760966-provide-a-local-emulator-or-increase-the-number-of). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I added my vote.

Comment: please vote for this feature here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/6760966-provide-a-local-emulator-or-increase-the-number-of

Answer (score 5):

There is a simulator published here - https://github.com/simonedeponti/AzureSearchEmulator which exposes REST APIs, which can help you test it on your local.